# styles/style.css No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: css

it seems my styles folder added under the web folder is not getting mapped by dispatcher servlet on my JSP's. I get

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/onlinebasket/styles/style.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'onlinebasket'
```

here's my dispatcher servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>onlinebasket</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and i this is my CSS URL on JSP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/styles/sytle.css"/>" type="text/css"/>
```

This folder is on the web folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL Mapping should be corrected to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>onlinebasket</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/onlinebasket/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: i had it like that before but i have to always prefix my URLs/hyperlinks with onlinebasket/ hence i changed to '/'. What' the difference between the two?

Comment: You are assigning a route to which your servlet should respond. In the former case it responds to all the requests whose URI starts with onlinebasket path, in the latter it reponds to root requests